# Refactor old functionality in symfony project

Tags: php, symfony, architecture, refactoring

I need to refactor my code from old symfony project. I have something like template provider. Each template is separate bundle with own form, twig template, provider (where I have name of template and path to twig file) and services.yml. Now I can put it to one bundle and I need an advice, how I can do it in best way. Each bundle still must have separate twig file (there are scripts depended from template type and data from form). But maybe there is some automagic to generate forms in dynamic way (a lot of forms have only one field with id)? How would you design a system that generates templates with own form and a twig file that uses variables from these forms? unfortunately I can not provide the source code for the project.
Greetings

Answer (score 0):

<s>Bundles are deprecated in Symfony 3.4 and event disabled in Symfony 4 unless you are creating a package that you intend to redistribute.</s>

I advise you to separate your code in different namespaces if it's important to you.

For the twig templates, as of Symfony 3.4, you can store them in the `templates/` directory at the root of your project directory. Again, if you need it so, you can store them in different sub-directories matching your different namespaces.

See the author's blog : [Symfony 4: Directory Structure | Articles - Fabien Potencier](http://fabien.potencier.org/symfony4-directory-structure.html)

[EDIT] As Cerad comments, I was mistaken. Bundles are not deprecated nor disbaled. It is Bundle inheritance that is deprecated in Symfony 3.4 and disabled in Symfony 4.

See details here : [New in Symfony 3.4: Deprecated bundle inheritance (Symfony Blog)](http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-3-4-deprecated-bundle-inheritance)

Comment: No, bundles are neither depreciated in 3.4 nor disabled in S4.  It's been recommended for quite some time not to divide your application code into bundles but you can still do so if the design calls for it.